Identify this movie: fight at a pizza joint
I have a vague recollection of a scene from a movie:
English, likely US release.   90's or 00 release.  
I recall a scene with a cop, eating dinner with his family at a NY style pizza joint.  Some thugs use foul language.    He gets mad, confronts them and either beats one up or handcuffs them in front of his family.  
edit:  It is possible they are on the second floor of the restaurant.   With tables arranged back to back along the 2nd floor railing that overlooks the first floor.  
His wife (possibly estranged) is horrified by how violent he has become.   Possible he's been working undercover, but I recall he announced he was a cop before the altercation, so he wasn't hiding it at the time.   
He and his wife argue about his approach, she admonishes him for what he did.  
It is possible that this was a date with a single mother and not his wife and kids.   

Sounds similar to the end of "Do the Right Thing," though I don't recall the cop being on a date.

I'm sure it's not that (as i watched that film last month) but it does point out that NY style pizza joint is vague.   My recollection is that the style was more modern.   Silver, blue, chrome coloring.
